# Inheritance static method in java

Tags: java

I know this question was asked billion times but how I can implement following:

I have class:

```
public class Product {
    ....

    public static Product fromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Product product = new Product();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        product.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.Product.TITLE)));
        ...
        return product;
    }

    public static List<Product> getProducts(Cursor cursor) {
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Product product = fromCursor(cursor);
                products.add(product);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return products;
    }
}
```

I want create other objects with this methods but i don't want each time implement method `getProducts` but i should implement `fromCursor`.
How can I generalize it?

Comment: have you looked at abstract classes?

Comment: @DaneBrick, yes, but i don't know how abstract classes can help me? Can you show me example?

Comment: Will the method getProducts be the same throughout the classes that implement it, if this is the case then you should use abstract classes. Or do you need both methods to change slightly due to different data types, if this is your case, then you should use generics.

Answer (score 0):

Use Generics

```
public class UtilProducts {


    public static <T> List<T> getProducts(Cursor cursor, T dummyProduct) {
          ...
          // you call here dummyProduct.fromCursor(cursor)
        return (List<T>) ...;
    }

public class Product{
      ...
      public static Product fromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Product product = new Product();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
            product.setTitle(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DB.Product.TITLE)));
        ...
        return product;
    }

}


 public class OtherProduct{
      ...
      public static OtherProduct fromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        OtherProduct product = new OtherProduct();

        return product;
    }

}
```

For the above implementation you would use  `UtilProducts.getProducts(cursor, new Product())` and `UtilProducts.getProducts(cursor, new OtherProduct())`

However, you must make sure that all of your products class "implement" a static method `fromCursor()`

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still can't understand how i can use it, because in getProducts i need use fromCursor method (check my example) and i need have ability overload fromCursor method.

Comment: This won't work.  You can't mix generics and static methods like you're trying to do.

Comment: @LouisWasserman What part won't work? If it is designed flaw. Yes, I aggree. You would want an interface for `fromCursor()`. When you extend Product you will need to rewrite the static method, but this is what @comalex3 asked for

Comment: dummyProduct.fromCursor won't even compile, much less do what you want it to do.

Comment: well, you do not need to make the method static since you already have `dummyProduct`

Comment: You made me doubt myself, but it is perfectly fine, it compiles and gives no error

Comment: @RaduIonescu " want an interface for fromCursor()" java doesn't allow do interface for static method or I'm wrong?

Comment: Works in Java 8, but the problem is the return type (which needs to change with your class and again you would need to use generics) and static methods are not inherited like non-static methods. Even if you define an interface it changes nothing in how you write the code, you would still need to define fromCursor in every class. The interface is a contract and makes sure you define fromCursor, other than that if you don't forget to define it, it behaves the same.